# Formato de fecha con moment

Tags: momentjs

Estoy tratando de obtener este formato con la librería moment.js

01/24/2022 10:14 PM GMT-0500

pero aún no se como poder anteponerle "GMT" en el tiempo...

Esto es lo que estoy intentando:

```
// datetime es la fecha en formato tiempo
moment(new Date(dateTime)).format('MM/DD/yyyy hh:mm A Z');
```

y lo que obtengo es :
01/24/2022 10:14 PM -05:00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hola creo que pudieras usar esta configuración

```
moment(new Date()).format('MM/DD/yyyy hh:mm A [GMT]ZZ');
```

el resultado para mi fue `01/24/2022 10:51 PM GMT-0500`

Comment: Muchas gracias 